# Google Android Sample MVVM - Why do they use MediatorLiveData instead of passing LiveData with getter?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I was analyzing Android architecture components sample app (**BasicSample**). Why do they use `MediatorLiveData` in `DataRepository` class if there is only **one** source attached to it?

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/DataRepository.java#L25-L31

```
mObservableProducts = new MediatorLiveData<>();

mObservableProducts.addSource(mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts(),
        productEntities -> {
            if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                mObservableProducts.postValue(productEntities);
            }
        });
```

I think they should just use `LiveData<List<ProductEntity>` coming from DAO and facilitate it with getter method:

```
public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
    return mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts();
}
```

Exactly how they did with other DAO requests:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/DataRepository.java#L47-L61

```
public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
    return mObservableProducts;
}

public LiveData<ProductEntity> loadProduct(final int productId) {
    return mDatabase.productDao().loadProduct(productId);
}

public LiveData<List<CommentEntity>> loadComments(final int productId) {
    return mDatabase.commentDao().loadComments(productId);
}

public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> searchProducts(String query) {
    return mDatabase.productDao().searchAllProducts(query);
}
```

The same question relates to `ProductListViewModel`. They again created `MediatorLiveData` only with one source.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/viewmodel/ProductListViewModel.java#L42-L46

```
mRepository = ((BasicApp) application).getRepository();
LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> products = mRepository.getProducts();

// observe the changes of the products from the database and forward them
mObservableProducts.addSource(products, mObservableProducts::setValue);
```

Comment: You are missing that they are intentionally filtering the DAO emissions before the initial data is inserted into the DB. This is what the MediatorLiveData you mentioned *does*.

Comment: Aaa OK :) So if I don't insert any data to the database at the first run I can be sure that the database was created before the first query so I can use standard `public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
    return mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts();
}` without creating `Mediator`?

Comment: Yes then you can use the standard dao without a mediator ;) technically if you didn't do the mediator dance, you could just have an empty view ready first and then the data would load when the data is inserted thanks to LiveData Room integration. So that mediator wouldn't even be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

They are intentionally filtering the DAO emissions before the initial data is inserted into the DB. This is what the MediatorLiveData you mentioned does.

If you don't need to wait for an "initial set of data to be loaded" like they do, then you can just ditch the `MediatorLiveData` and use `mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts();` directly.